# In Swift, how to cast to protocol with associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, protocols, associated-types

In the following code, I want to test if `x` is a `SpecialController`. If it is, I want to get the `currentValue` as a `SpecialValue`. How do you do this? If not with a cast, then some other technique.

The last line there won't compile. There error is: *Protocol "SpecialController" can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.*

```
protocol SpecialController {
    associatedtype SpecialValueType : SpecialValue
    var currentValue: SpecialValueType? { get }
}
...
var x: AnyObject = ...
if let sc = x as? SpecialController {  // does not compile
```

Comment: swift 5.7: 
    if let sc = x as? any SpecialController

Comment: `if let sc = x as? ObjectName & ProtocolName`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, Swift doesn't currently support the use of protocols with associated types as actual types. This however [is technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41695792/2976878) for the compiler to do; and it [may well be implemented in a future version of the language](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generalized-existentials).

A simple solution in your case is to define a 'shadow protocol' that `SpecialController` derives from, and allows you to access `currentValue` through a protocol requirement that type erases it:

```
// This assumes SpecialValue doesn't have associated types – if it does, you can
// repeat the same logic by adding TypeErasedSpecialValue, and then using that.
protocol SpecialValue {
  // ...
}

protocol TypeErasedSpecialController {
  var typeErasedCurrentValue: SpecialValue? { get }
}

protocol SpecialController : TypeErasedSpecialController {
  associatedtype SpecialValueType : SpecialValue
  var currentValue: SpecialValueType? { get }
}

extension SpecialController {
  var typeErasedCurrentValue: SpecialValue? { return currentValue }
}

extension String : SpecialValue {}

struct S : SpecialController {
  var currentValue: String?
}

var x: Any = S(currentValue: "Hello World!")
if let sc = x as? TypeErasedSpecialController {
  print(sc.typeErasedCurrentValue as Any) // Optional("Hello World!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edited to fix: `: SpecialValue`, not `= SpecialValue`]

This is not possible. `SpecialValueController` is an "incomplete type" conceptually so the compiler cannot know. `SpecialValueType`, although it *is constrained by* `SpecialValue`, it is not known until it is determined by any adopting class. So it is a really placeholder with inadequate information. `as?`-ness cannot be checked.

You could have a base class that adopts `SpecialController` with a *concrete* type for `SpecialValueController`, and have multiple child classes that inherit from the adopting class, if you're still seeking a degree of polymorphism.

Comment: The fact that `currentValue` is a `SpecialValue` is not something that can be changed by any adopting class.  You are guaranteed that the currentValue is a `SpecialValue` or a subtype of it.

Comment: @RobN If you don't take my word for it, see this very similar issue where a 320k rep guy explains the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629358/why-is-this-causing-so-much-trouble-protocols-and-typealiases-on-their-associa/39629635#39629635

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to do so with recent versions of Swift (tested with 5.7)

Example:

```
protocol SpecialValue {}

protocol SpecialController {
    associatedtype SpecialValueType: SpecialValue
    var currentValue: SpecialValueType? { get }
}
extension String: SpecialValue {}

struct S: SpecialController {
  var currentValue: String?
}
var x: Any = S(currentValue: "Hello World!")

if let x = x as? any SpecialController {
    print(x.currentValue)
}
print(x is any SpecialController)
print(type(of: x) is any SpecialController.Type)
```

Output:

```
Optional("Hello World!")
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `SpecialController` isn't a single type. You can think of associated types as a kind of generics. A `SpecialController` with its `SpecialValueType` being an `Int` is a completely different type from a `SpecialController` with its `SpecialValueType` being an `String`, just like how `Optional<Int>` is a completely different type from `Optional<String>`.

Because of this, it doesn't make any sense to cast to `SpecialValueType`, because that would gloss over the associated type, and allow you to use (for example) a `SpecialController` with its `SpecialValueType` being an `Int` where a `SpecialController` with its `SpecialValueType` being a `String` is expected.

As compiler suggests, the only way `SpecialController` can be used is as a generic constraint. You can have a function that's generic over `T`, with the constraint that `T` must be a `SpecialController`. The domain of `T` now spans all the various concrete types of `SpecialController`, such as one with an `Int` associated type, and one with a `String`. For each possible associated type, there's a distinct `SpecialController`, and by extension, a distinct `T`.

To draw out the `Optional<T>` analogy further. Imagine if what you're trying to do was possible. It would be much like this:

```
func funcThatExpectsIntOptional(_: Int?) {}

let x: Optional<String> = "An optional string"
// Without its generic type parameter, this is an incomplete type. suppose this were valid
let y = x as! Optional
funcThatExpectsIntOptional(y) // boom.
```

Comment: My associated type has a constraint on it. I know that whatever `currentValue` is, it must be a `SpecialValue` or a subtype of it.  So with your `Optional` analogy, what I'm really trying to do is... given an `Optional<X>` where I know `X : SpecialValue` just get the value out of it.

Comment: That's not a constraint. It's a default.

Comment: @BaseZen Notice that I use a colon, not an equals sign. If you adopt `SpecialController`, then `currentValue`'s type must be `SpecialValue` or a subtype.

Comment: Not a problem in Obj-C however. :)

Comment: @nielsbot Obj-C's weak typing is far far away from where this is at :p

Comment: Ah I see. Misread that. However, we're still both right. :-) The point remains that a protocol with an associated type is considered incomplete.

Comment: @RobN That constraint doesn't address the issue. It limits the domain of possible concrete types `SpecialController ` can be, but `SpecialController ` still represents a set of multiple separate types, one per every `SpecialValue` type.

Comment: I'm don't mean to argue with either of you about what Swift thinks. I'm just explaining that what I'm saying is logically sane, so it seems their could be a way to say it the language. That's why I can do it in, for example, Java, with runtime type-checked casts.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Of course. But note that `as?` is being used.. this is a check that can fail at runtime. Anyway, no need to dwell on that in this thread.

Comment: @RobN It's actually not sane, and Java should *not* allow it. The only reason it does is because its generics system is a bodged compile-time abstraction over the `Object` type. Once your generalized code compiles, it's all `Object` under the hood, with unrestricted ability to do run time casts and such. You can achieve the same in Swift with `Any`... but you shouldn't.

Comment: @RobN Would you agree that `Array` is an incomplete type?

Comment: Sure, "incomplete", or I've heard other terms like "higher kinded" or "existential". Either way, does it not make logical sense to ask "Is x an Array?" without specifying the type parameter to Array? That question has a clear true/false answer for all objects/values, right?

Comment: @RobN Yes, it's kind of like a higher kinder a type, a type constructor that takes a type parameter (the element type) and uses it to construct your new array type. The question isn't quite valid, because `Array` on its own is not a type. `Array of something` is a type, and perhaps you don't care for what that "something" is, so it can be "anything". You can perform this check in swift: `let isArray = ([1, 2, 3] as Any) is Array<Any>`

Comment: @RobN So if you agree that `Array` is an incomplete type, what about `SpecialController`? If I tell you I have an instance of `SpecialController`, have I provided sufficient type information to explain all aspects of the behaviour of `SpecialController`?

Comment: No, but you provided enough that we know it has a property called `currentValue`, whose value is of type `SpecialValue`, or a subtype. I should be able to get at that value, somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127222/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-rob-n).