# Swift - make String conform to RandomAccessCollection

Tags: swift

According to Swift 5 docs, String has method `randomElement()` with complexity `O(1)` or `O(*n*)` depending on conformance to `RandomAccessCollection` protocol.

[image: randomElement method description]

Therefore, I am wondering **how to make cases where randomElement() of String complexity will be O(1).**

My string is just:

```
let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I check if my particular string conforms to RandomAccessCollection?
2. How to create / remove conformance to RandomAccessCollection protocol from a string?

Comment: Based on @Matt's answer, just do `let letters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")` to get O(1)

Comment: @vacawama thanks, already did this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randomElement` is a requirement of the `Collection` protocol, as you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2995109-randomelement).

So `String` is merely conforming to `Collection` by implementing this method, and the documentation comment is just a copy-paste from the original one in `Collection`.

If you read the documentation comment in the context of `Collection` instead of `String`, it makes a lot more sense. It's saying that if `self` is also a `RandomAccessCollection`, then it's O(1), otherwise it's O(n).

`String` *does not* conform to `RandomAccessCollection`, as you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#relationships), so `String.randomElement` is O(n).

EDIT:

To check if something is a `RandomAccessCollection` of `Character`, you can't do it directly with `is`, because `RandomAccessCollection` has associated types. One way to do this is to define a function that accepts a constrained type parameter:

```
let letters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
func f<T>(_ x: T) where T : RandomAccessCollection, T.Element == Character {}
f(letters) // if this compiles, then Array<Character> conforms to RandomAccessCollection and Element is Character
```

Comment: One could consider this a bug in the automatically generated documentation. The documentation of the protocol methods are verbatim copied into the documentation of all conforming types. (Even the given example in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997145-randomelement is not about a random element in a string.)

Comment: OK, I will treat documentation less seriously. Please, give an example of RandomAccessCollection of characters and how to verify that this collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection.

Comment: `[Character]` is a `RandomAccessCollection`, since [`Array` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array#relationships) @OleksiiShnyra

Comment: @Sweeper I need to check it programmatically. Something like below, but working example. Any ideas? 

```let letters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

if letters.self is RandomAccessCollection.Type {
    print("conforms")
}```

Comment: @OleksiiShnyra: Only *types* can conform to a protocol, not *instances* of a type.

Comment: @MartinR code works fine with
```if letters.self is Array<Character> {
    print("conforms")
}``` but not sure how to make it with ```letters.self is RandomAccessCollection.Type```

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for edits, but I need a run-time check, simple true / false condition.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230168/checking-conforms-protocol-with-associatedtype-in-swift).

Comment: Building on your idea @Sweeper, you can create two generic functions `isRandomAccessCollection` one with a type constraint to `RandomAccessCollection` that returns `true` and the other with no constraint that returns `false`.  Then `isRandomAccessCollection("abc")` returns `false`, but `isRandomAccessCollection(Array("abc"))` returns `true`.

Comment: @vacawama I interpreted a "runtime-check" as the OP having a variable of an unknown type (`Any`) and wants to check if it is a `RandomAccessCollection`.

Comment: Ah I see.  My pair of functions is useful for just quickly exploring which types of objects are RandomAccessCollections ... strings - no, Array(string) - yes, dictionary - no, dictionary.keys - no, etc.

Answer (score 8):

A string is never a random access collection. If that’s what you want, cast to an Array.

Comment: If String cannot conform to RandomAccessCollection - why such case even described in documentation then?

Comment: Because that documentation is not just for String.

Comment: Comment about complexity is written inside `extension String` therefore it should be related to string.

Comment: Yes it should be. But it isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` in swift already conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`

[image]